# Proving that $2\arcsin\left(\frac{d_{c}(x,y)}{2}\right)=d_{s}(x,y)$, $\forall x,y\in\Bbb{S}^{n}$.

Tags: geometry

I have been tasked with showing that $\forall x,y\in\Bbb{S}^{n}$: $$2\arcsin\left(\frac{d_{c}(x,y)}{2}\right)=d_{s}(x,y)$$

In the exercise:

$\Bbb{S}^{n}$ denotes $\{x\in\Bbb{R}^{n+1}:|x|=1\}$.
$d_{c}$ is the function defined as follows: $\forall x,y\in\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$, $d_{c}(x,y)=|x-y|$.
$d_{s}$ is the function defined as follows: $\forall x,y\in\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$, $d_{s}(x,y)=\arccos(x\cdot y)$.

I am able to do this, in the case where $n=1$, by using the fact that in a right angled triangle, $\sin=\frac{opposite}{hypothenuse}$. However, I do not think that this is the right approach at all, since I do not see how this method can be extended for any $n$.

We have been told that the proof is to be completed via direct computation.

I would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the plane through $O, x$ and $y$  we measure $\theta=\angle(Ox, Oy)$.

Euclidian distance is $|x -y|=2\dfrac{|x-y|}{2}=2\arcsin{\dfrac{|x-y|}{2}}$ because in the triangle formed by the origin, the midpoint of $x-y$ and $x$ is rectangle triangle, then $\sin\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)=\dfrac{|x-y|}{2}$

On the other hand let $x, y$ the "length" of the arc $xy$ is equal to the angle between the vectors $Ox$ and $Oy$ is $\cos\theta$

Then, by the use of cosine formula, we get $|x−y|^2=|x|^2+|y|^2−2|x||y|\cos\theta$
$$|x−y|^2=2−2\cos\theta=2(1-\cos\theta)=4\sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})$$

Therefore
$$|x−y|=2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$